Brother scanner missing : start up error messages
I recently moved from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. Since that, I have problems at the boot : it's quite slow. Moreover, I have a problem with my network Brother MFC-9140cdn printer. Indeed, I still can print, but I can't scan anything. The scanner is impossible to reach, by simple-scan or Xsane.
Here is some information for you :
greg@greg-NUC11TNKv7:~$ journalctl --no-pager -b -p err
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: x86/mktme: No known encryption algorithm is supported: 0x0
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^SPI1.SPFD.CVFD (20230628/dspkginit-438)
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^SPI1.SPFD.CVFD (20230628/dspkginit-438)
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20230628/dspkginit-438)
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - ^XHCI.RHUB.HS04.VI2C (20230628/dspkginit-438)
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: Serial bus multi instantiate pseudo device driver INT3515:00: error -ENXIO: IRQ index 1 not found
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: Serial bus multi instantiate pseudo device driver INT3515:00: error -ENXIO: Error requesting irq at index 1
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: usb usb2-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 kernel: usb usb2-port3: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd-udevd[534]: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-brscan4-libsane-type1.rules:9 Invalid key 'SYSFS'.
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd-udevd[534]: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1-inst.rules:14 Invalid key 'SYSFS'.
oct. 20 08:03:13 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd-udevd[534]: /etc/udev/rules.d/60-brother-libsane-type1.rules:17 Invalid key 'SYSFS'.
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 bluetoothd[1516]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
oct. 20 08:03:50 greg-NUC11TNKv7 bluetoothd[1516]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
oct. 20 08:03:51 greg-NUC11TNKv7 canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[1937]: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/b025a6fc36ea45af83126cecf56f5f71/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
oct. 20 08:05:31 greg-NUC11TNKv7 gdm-password][2805]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
oct. 20 08:05:31 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd[2816]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-3080.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
oct. 20 08:05:31 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd[2816]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-3073.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
oct. 20 08:05:31 greg-NUC11TNKv7 systemd[2816]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-3075.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
greg@greg-NUC11TNKv7:~$ 

Here are the content of the three rules files I found in /etc/udev/rules.d
#
#   udev rules 
#

ACTION!="add", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_1"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_1"
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_2"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
#MODE="0666"
#GROUP="scanner"
ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
#SYMLINK+="scanner-%k"
LABEL="brother_mfp_end"

#
#   udev rules sample for Brother MFP
#         version 1.0.2-0
#
#   Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Brother. Industries, Ltd.
#
#   copy to /etc/udev/rules.d or /lib/udev/rules.d
#

ACTION!="add", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_1"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_1"


SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_2"

#  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
#  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="02", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
#  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_3"
#  GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
#  LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_3"

ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"

#MODE="0666"
#GROUP="scanner"
ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
#SYMLINK+="scanner-%k"


LABEL="brother_mfp_end"

#
#   udev rules sample for Brother MFP
#         version 1.0.2-0
#
#   Copyright (C) 2012-2017 Brother. Industries, Ltd.
#
#   copy to /etc/udev/rules.d or /lib/udev/rules.d
#

ACTION!="add", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_1"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb_device", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_1"
SYSFS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", GOTO="brother_mfp_udev_2"
GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
LABEL="brother_mfp_udev_2"
ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}!="0ff", GOTO="brother_mfp_end"
#MODE="0666"
#GROUP="scanner"
ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
#SYMLINK+="scanner-%k"
LABEL="brother_mfp_end"

So, my question are :

do you think the error I see on boot can be solved by commenting the lines beginning with SYSFS (I didn't try because I don't have the skills to anticipate the result)

Do you think it could solve my scanner problem too ?


Thx very much for any help.
